# Regex to select the string between two texts

Tags: regex

I have a code like:

```
<p>Also: <a>text 1</a></p> <p><a> text 2 </a></p>
```

I am using a regex like this, I just want to remove until the first `</P>`

```
<p>Also:(.*?)</p>
```

and the output is

```
empty
```

How do I select until the first `</p>` from `<p>Also`?

Comment: can we see code?

Comment: i have the article full of p and a tag i just want to remove this p tag starting with "Also"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a regex like this:

```
/(?<=<p>Also:).+?(?=<\/p>)/i
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/3)

or

```
/^.*?(?<=<p>Also:).+?(?=<\/p>)/gi
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/4)

Answer (score 0):

I tried VB.NET and found that your regex pattern works for your input, However, When I tried in regexr.com I found that the foward slash "/" should be escaped.
You could try this:

```
<p>Also:(.+?)<\/p>
```

Note: For HTML, I won't recommend you to use regex. It's better to use an HTML parser depending on your programming language.